# PHP executing in browser timeout and echo output in the same line

Tags: php

I have a script which send emails to my clients

```
<?  
    set_time_limit(0);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $_SESSION['start_time'] = time();
            $strSubject = strip_tags($_POST["txtSubject"]);
            $strSubject = utf8_encode($strSubject);
            $strMessage = $_POST["txtDescription"];
            $txtFormName = $_POST["txtFormName"];
            $txtFormName = utf8_encode($txtFormName);
            $txtFormEmail = $_POST["txtFormEmail"];
            $mailSended = 0;
                $count = 0;
                $Ccount = 0;
                foreach($_FILES['fileAttach']['error'] as $status){
                    if($status === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                    $fname[] = $_FILES['fileAttach']['name'][$Ccount];
                    $tmp_path[] = $_FILES['fileAttach']['tmp_name'][$Ccount];
                    $ftype[] =  $_FILES['fileAttach']['type'][$Ccount];
                        $count++;
                    }
                    $Ccount++;
                }
            //if not empty post txtTo
        if(!empty($_POST['txtTo'])){
            $recipients = str_replace(';',',', $_POST['txtTo']);
            $recipients = explode(',', $recipients);

            foreach ($recipients as $ReCEmail)  {
            ob_start();   
                SendEmails($ReCEmail,$strSubject,$strMessage,$txtFormName,$txtFormEmail,$fname,$ftype,$tmp_path);
            ob_end_flush();
            } 
        }    //if empty post txtTo  takes emails from file
        else 
        {
            $handle = fopen(getcwd() . "/emails.txt", "r");
            if ($handle) {
                while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                ob_start();
                    SendEmails($line,$strSubject,$strMessage,$txtFormName,$txtFormEmail,$fname,$ftype,$tmp_path);
                ob_end_flush(); 
                }
                fclose($handle);
            } else {
                echo "error opening the file.";
            } 
        }

        function SendEmails($vasia,$strSubject,$strMessage,$txtFormName,$txtFormEmail,$fname,$ftypes,$tmp_path) {

            $strTo = $vasia; 
            $txtFormName = utf8_decode($txtFormName);
            $strSid = md5(uniqid(time(),true)).base_convert(time() * 2, 10, 36);  
            $strHeader = "X-Priority: 0 (Highest)" .PHP_EOL; 
            $strHeader .= "Importance: High" .PHP_EOL;
            $strHeader .= "From: ".$txtFormName." <".strip_tags($txtFormEmail).">" .PHP_EOL ."Reply-To: ".strip_tags($txtFormEmail);
            $strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.00" .PHP_EOL;
            if(count($fname) == 0) 
            {
                $strHeader .= "Content-type:text; charset=\"UTF-8\"" .PHP_EOL;
                $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit"  .PHP_EOL;
                $strHeader .= $strMessage .PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                $strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strSid."\"".PHP_EOL;
                $strMSG = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.".PHP_EOL .PHP_EOL;
                $strMSG .= "---".$strSid.PHP_EOL;
                $strMSG .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"".PHP_EOL;
                $strMSG .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" .PHP_EOL .PHP_EOL;
                $strMSG .= $strMessage .PHP_EOL;
                    //*** Attachment ***//  
                    for($x=0;$x<count($fname);$x++)  
                    {  
                        if($fname[$x] != "")  
                        {  
                            $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($tmp_path[$x]))); 
                            $strMSG .= "--".$strSid.PHP_EOL;                    
                            $strMSG .= "Content-Type: ".$ftypes[$x]."; name=\"".$fname[$x]."\"".PHP_EOL;
                            $strMSG .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".PHP_EOL;
                            $strMSG .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$fname[$x]."\"".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
                            $strMSG .= $strContent.PHP_EOL;
                        }
                    }
                $strMSG .= "--".$strSid."--";

            }

            // sleep(3) 1 email in 3 sec, 20 emails in 1 min, 1200 email in 1 hour
            // sleep(4) 1 email in 4 sec, 15 emails in 1 min, 900 email in 1 hour
            sleep(4); 
            $flgSend = mail($strTo,utf8_decode($strSubject),$strMSG,$strHeader);  
            global $mailSended,$diff;
            $mailSended++;
                if($flgSend)  
                {  
                    echo "</br> $vasia Mail send completed." ."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    echo "</br> $vasia Cannot send mail. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";  
                }
                $end_time = time();
                $diff = $end_time - $_SESSION['start_time'];
                echo "Sent " . $mailSended . " emails in " .secondsToTime($diff);   
                ob_flush();
        } 

    function secondsToTime($s)
    {
        $h = floor($s / 3600);
        $s -= $h * 3600;
        $m = floor($s / 60);
        $s -= $m * 60;
        return $h.':'.sprintf('%02d', $m).':'.sprintf('%02d', $s);
    }

    ?>
```

Questions

1. How to show in browser echo output in the same line clearing last echo output?
2. How prevent browser timeouts until script is working? I want to see in real time echo output!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP does not execute in the browser, it executes on the server and then **it's output** is sent to the browser. Once the server sends the script's output it no longer has any control over it. Therefore, you cannot "replace" one echo with another. You need Javascript to do something like that.

Your PHP is not timing out. You've got `set_time_limit(0);` at the top which removes the time limit. If something is timing out it's not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I would fall back to Javascript if you want to hide the previous line etc. php renders on the server. Check you php.ini and see your timeout sometimes you are not able to override these settings. The setting you are looking for is

```
max_execution_time
```

Good luck.